# How do I distinguish between these 2 MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have these routes in my area registration. 
It seems the second route is giving me resource Not found error.

```
            context.MapRoute(
                "viewer",
                "forum/{id}",
                new { controller = "View", action = "Index" }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "contacts",
                "forum/contacts",
                new { controller = "Contacts", action = "Index" }
            );

        context.MapRoute(
            "app_home",
            "forum/",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

It seems the first route is blocking the urls for the second one.
The action's controllers are different: Test and Contacts.

Sample url for first route:

```
www.<mysite>/forum/12345  <-- view forum 12345
```

Sample url for second route:

```
www.<mysite>/forum/contacts  <-- view contacts homepage
```

Sample url for third route:

```
www.<mysite>/forum  <-- forum homepage
```

How can I make these urls distinct in the routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `contacts` route first.

Routes are ordered; the routing engine will always select the first matching route.
Therefore, you should always put the most specific routes first.

Comment: I have /contacts in second url. Why it is matched by the first one?

Comment: @user762196, probably because the word `contacts` is being considered the `{id}` of the first route.

Comment: How do I tell router to distinct between /Id and /Contacts? Any way?

Comment: Slaks is correct. Switch the order because `contacts` is being passed to View/Action as the id. If you switch them it will work as he said. It just matches the first route that the url _can_ match. Since `forum/contacts` can match `forum/{id}' then it stops at that one.

Comment: You could also add a constraint to the `{id}` parameter to make it not match `contacts`

Comment: Any small example on how to add constraint on Id? The switching prder seems working though. But I might need the constraint as well.

Comment: You don't need the constraint as well.  Constraints are the fourth parameter to `MapRoute`  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-route-constraint-cs  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs